# digitalWrite()とSerial1.write()の切り替えについて

Tags: arduino

#### 実現したいこと

Arduino DueでdigitalWrite()とSerial1.write()の切り替えをしたいです。
しかしdigitalWrite()からSerial1.write()を実行すると正しくシリアル通信をすることができません。
シリアルデータを送信すると1回目の送信には成功しますが、2回目以降は0が送信されてしまいます。
ちなみにArduino Megaでは切り替えをすることができていて、通信することができます。
原因と下記の理想の受信データにする方法を教えていただきたいです。
※この対象Dueの通信相手は別DueのSerial1のtx/rxで、その別DueはSerial1で受信したデータをそのまま16進数でUSBケーブルで接続したPCのシリアルモニタに送っています。

#### 該当のソースコード

```
void setup() {
    const byte txData[6] = { 0xAA, 0xBB, 0xCC, 0xDD, 0xEE, 0xFF };

    //Serial1.write (1回目)
    Serial1.begin(9600);
    Serial1.write(txData, 6);
    Serial1.end();
    delay(1000);

    //digitalWrite
    pinMode(18, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(18, LOW);
    delay(50);
    digitalWrite(18, HIGH);
    delay(100);

    //Serial1.write (2回目以降)
    for(byte i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        Serial1.begin(9600);
        Serial1.write(txData, 3);
        Serial1.flush();
        Serial1.end();
        delay(1000);
    }
}

void loop() {
    
}
```

#### シリアルモニタ(理想の受信データ)

```
AA BB CC DD EE FF
AA BB CC
AA BB CC
AA BB CC
AA BB CC
AA BB CC
```

#### シリアルモニタ(実際の受信データ)

```
AA BB CC DD EE FF
00
```

#### 接続図

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

#### 補足情報

【Arduino Due】
https://store-usa.arduino.cc/collections/boards/products/arduino-due
https://content.arduino.cc/assets/A000056-full-pinout.pdf

【データシート】
https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-11057-32-bit-Cortex-M3-Microcontroller-SAM3X-SAM3A_Datasheet.pdf

#### マルチポスト

https://teratail.com/questions/h3km9w6nkmhjgm
https://qiita.com/alyn/questions/78d9963e81f53ab13f75
[digitalWrite()とSerial1.write()の切り替えについて](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/91802/digitalwrite%e3%81%a8serial1-write%e3%81%ae%e5%88%87%e3%82%8a%e6%9b%bf%e3%81%88%e3%81%ab%e3%81%a4%e3%81%84%e3%81%a6)

Answer (score 0):

以下の通りに書き換えれば同じ動作をさせることができそうです。
根本的な解決ではありませんが、これで解決にします。

**変更前:**

```
digitalWrite(18, LOW); delay(50);
```

**変更後:**

```
uint8_t Zero[1] = { 0 }; Serial1.begin(160); Serial1.write(Zero, 1);
```

Comment: 意図していた解答をいただきましたので追記します↓
https://teratail.com/questions/h3km9w6nkmhjgm#reply-6yb1hdojsslocq